# The rate for a room is £30, but breakfast is extra.(the verb "be" as "exist")

Tags: word-usage, verb-usage

> The rate for a room is £30, but breakfast **is** extra.

The verb "**is**" in the sentence above means "exists", thus, extra is an adverb?

Comment: No, it's an adjective functioning as predicative complement of "be". It relates to a predicand, i.e. "breakfast". Non-_ly_ adverbs don't function as predicative complement. The meaning is "extra cost".

Answer (score 1):

"Is" here is being used as a ***copula***, that is as a sort of grammatical equals sign. When a form of "to be" is used  as copula, in means that two things are equal or identical in some way.The example can be thought of as a shorthand for:

> The rate for a room is £30, but there is an extra charge for breakfast.

The word "extra" is functioning as an adjective, but the word it modifies ("charge" or "cost") has been omitted.